# getting garbage number in derived template class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, derived-class, dot-product

I am trying to calculate dot product in derived template class but it keeps returning garbage number

**Example:** exponential number.

I figure it might be something has to do with the constructor in the derived class? I called base class copy constructor from derived class but am not sure if I should initialize private members from base class. Thanks in advance!

```
template <typename T>//declared as a template of type T

NumericArray<T>::NumericArray(): Array<T>() {       //constructor
    cout <<"The NumArray constructor has been called." << endl;
}

template <typename T>//declared as a template of type T

NumericArray<T>::NumericArray(int new_size): Array<T>(new_size){    
    //parameter constructor
    cout << "The NumArray parameter constructor has been called." << endl;
}

template <typename T>

NumericArray<T>::NumericArray(const NumericArray<T>& arr) : Array<T>
(arr) { //copy constructor
    cout << "The NumArray copy constructor has been called." << endl;
}

template <typename T>       //declared as a template of type T

NumericArray<T>::~NumericArray() {              //destructor
    cout << "The destructor of NumArray." << endl;
}

template <typename T>//declared as a template of type T

double NumericArray<T>::DotProduct(const NumericArray<T>& a)    const           
//dot product
{

    if ((*this).size() != a.size())
        throw NumArrayException();//throw exception if the sizes are not the same

        double dotProduct = 0;//initialize dot product

        for (int i = 0; i < (*this).size(); i++)    //iterates the elements
        {
            dotProduct += (a.getElement(i) )* (NumericArray::getElement(i));        
        //calculate dot product
        }

        return dotProduct;

}
```

and in the base Array class...

```
template <typename T>

Array<T>::Array(int size)
{
    m_size = size; //set the size to be the input size
    m_data = new T[size]; //set the dynamic array to be of different size
    //cout << "size constructor" << endl;
}

template <typename T>

Array<T>::Array(const Array<T>& arr)
{
    m_size = arr.m_size;        //copy to be same size
    m_data = new T[m_size]; //copy dynamic memory of new size

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.m_size; i++) //loop through each element of new array
    {
        m_data[i] = arr.m_data[i];  //copy each new array element
    }

    cout << "copy constructor is used." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about `std::vector`, which is generally preferential to allocating arrays with `new`. With newer C++ you get better iteration support, like [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and more. Also `this->size` is preferable to `(*this).size`.

Comment: When you get garbled data you're often dealing with uninitialized values. That can be from walking off the end of an array or failing to initialize them properly in the first place. Are you sure that `new` is actually zeroing out your values? It may just be allocating memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am thinking the problem comes from the base class constructor since the NumericArray class calls base class constructor and can't explicitly use private member from base. How would you initialize m_data in base? Can you do that with new?